# Error for Dispatch Page on Salesforce1

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, salesforce1-app

I have a dispatch page on account.When i am crearting a "new record" meaning new button the dispatch page redirects to a different page depending on the record type selected. It is working fine on the pc but when I try it on Salesforce1 it is giving an error message:

> The page you are to access is not supported on mobile devices.

Steps I have taken:

1.Enabled the dispatch for Salesforce1.

2.Enabled all the Visualforce page that we are redirecting to.

I don't understand what I am I missing here.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue and have a solution. Here is the setup:

1. Visualforce override for New and Edit
2. Object has multiple recordtypes, so the VF page is a dispatch page to forward the user to the right URL for the selected recordtype.
3. When creating the override, the option to "Skip Record Type Selection Page" is NOT checked.

I've found that it is the recordtype selection page that is causing the error. Checking this box allows the VF page to function, but this means that you have to build your own record type selection page and this custom record type selection page will be used in both Salesforce1 and in the browser.

If you want to build your own recordtype selection page that looks as much like the default selection page as possible, you'll need to also build a mobile recordtype selection page. Then you can use the JavaScript navigation object to send users to the mobile record type selection page when they are in Salesforce1.

Comment: Without taking a look, I'm 90% sure this is the answer. Pretty sure this is addressed in the next release.

Comment: This is still an issue today. The record type page is still not supported in Salesforce1 and we have been told to implement a custom solution for this need. No estimate has been communicated yet for when this can be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Salesforce1 navigation API.
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/salesforce1/Content/vf_dev_best_practices_navigation.htm

Someone already posted a similar question here. (check the answer from Ryan)
[Outer link to VF page in Salesforce1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23167/outer-link-to-vf-page-in-salesforce1)

Comment: Problem here is it is a new button which is overridden by dispatcher page so how will the javascript be called from new button.

Comment: I don't get it. Your "dispatcher page" is a visualforce page right? So you have control of this new button? Then just set the onclick event of your button to use the Salesforce1 navigation API javascript. I think it would help if you explain a bit more or post the code of how your dispatcher page looks like and how you would want the page to behave. I suggest updating your original question with this info.